# How to pre-select a jquery mobile input button?

Tags: jquery, button, jquery-mobile

I've done a jquery-mobile controlgroup using input buttons like this:

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="panelSwitcher">
   <input type="button" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="gallery" value="Gallerie" class="viewGrid" />
   <input type="button" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="panels" value="Panels" class="viewPanel" />
   <input type="button" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="detail"  value="Detail" class="viewDetail"  />
</div>
```

I'm using this to switch views (add/drop a single class, rest CSS), so I don't really want to do this using link tags (empty href/alt) and event-binding. Radio-button-form is also too complicated, plus you cannot do icon only radios.

So input `type=button`.

**Question:**
I'm loading my page in gridview, so I want to have the gridview button preselected. I know I can jQuery `addClass('ui-btn-active')` to the parent `.ui-btn` element, but I want to know if there is a markup-only solution, too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this was answered some time ago, but I think the correct answer is to set add the "ui-btn-active" class on the div containing the button.

Comment: Thanks for this, but i am using radio buttons and when adding the active class to the label it would be highlighted for the first call but remains if i select another option. any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to find a solution by giving a data-theme="b" for the selected button. data-theme="b" closely resembles the active state. A demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/hz9Q3/

Let me know if that helps.